# spring boot app startup failed in java 11 with gradle

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-11

I am upgrading my spring boot app from java 1.8 to java 11. I am using spring boot 1.5.12.RELEASE version and gradle 6.6.1 version. Gradle build is success but when try to run the app , i am seeing the below error. I am stuck with this from last 2 days. we have upgraded similar app from java 1.8 to 11 with same spring boot version as above but using Maven. Any help is highly appreciated. I tried in google with different solutions but could not resolve.

```
Task :bootRun FAILED
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:93)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getInitialUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:56)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.<init>(Restarter.java:140)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.initialize(Restarter.java:583)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:67)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:45)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:69)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:292)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
        at com.App.main(App.java:16)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: upgrade spring-boot also.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot 1.5 is not compatible with Java 11. It's also no longer supported. You can either stick with Java 8 and continue to use Spring Boot 1.5 or upgrade to Spring Boot 2.3.x or 2.4.x which both support Java 11 (in addition to still supporting Java 8).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response 
@Andy Wilkinson . But we were able to migrate our other spring boot app which is in 1.5.12 to java 11 . But we are using Maven not gradle. does this also matters?

Comment: No, the build system doesn't matter. The specific problem you're seeing is with Devtools. Perhaps your Maven-based project wasn't use it? Either way, Spring Boot 1.5 doesn't support Java 11 and, even if it happens to work, you shouldn't rely on it as it's never been tested.